# Creating hyperlinks in documents and messages

Tags: algorithms, regular-expressions

In Sweden the abbreviation "t.ex." means "for example" ("till exempel") and it is extremely common. Every time I write that t.ex. in an email or in a text message it gets marked up as a clickable hyperlink which damages my message.

How difficult is it to match hyperlinks without getting false positives?

I remember seeing a regex about 150 lines long to do this, including the `gopher://` protocol. How come making hyperlinks is still so poorly developed? I use django's filter `urlize` myself and it is pretty restrictive - it probably wouldn't expect that T.EX is a link.

Why is it not very standardized even though the format is so old?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urlize` is restrictive because it works with content which, in substance, is very different compared to SMS. The goal of `urlize` *is* to be restrictive, because:

- Developers would usually include the scheme by themselves,
- They won't be very annoyed if they don't and `urlize` will consider that `example.com` is not a valid URI, while `http://example.com` is.
- They will be extremely disappointed by false positives. For instance, they would probably be angry if Node.js would be considered an URI.

In the world of SMS, things are different:

- End users won't write `http://`, because is makes no sense (have you ever written `http://` on a 4.7 inch display on a bus?).
- If they actually typed an URI such as `goo.gl` and the recipient can't click on it, copy-pasting the address on a 4.7 inch display on a bus would be annoying.
- The recipients don't care that some text which is not an URI gets underlined and colored in blue. They just dismiss the formatting if they know that this is not an URI. That's one of the differences between humans and machines. In:

  > I'll be late, and [b.t.w](http://example.com/) we'll have pizza tonight.

  many machines would consider `b.t.w` a link because it has a different color or has a `<a>` markup around it, while most humans will just dismiss the inconsistent formatting, simply because semantically, it doesn't make sense.

When you have to deal with user's input, especially in restrictive conditions (4.7 inch tactile screen on a bus), you have to be more permissive. You can't expect everyone to use `(541) 754-3010` format to enter phone numbers, so `75 13010` should be considered valid.

BTW, if hyperlinks over “t.ex” bother you that much, you may try “t. ex.” instead. Unfortunately, it wastes two additional characters. The form “t-ex” may also be solution, depending on the Sweden syntax.

Comment: I like the last idea, using a different spelling. I think the `urlize` should be "smarter" for instance pre-fetching and checking what the site is or making a suggesting, instead of just assuming that everything dot is a link.